# How to create a crossed-out © symbol?

Tags: unicode, special-characters

I am trying to figure out how best to produce a "slashed-out" Copyright symbol. The symbol is intended to indicate the absence of Copyright restriction on a published work, such as a work in the Public Domain.

So far, I have been able to combine a reverse solidus with the Copyright symbol as can be seen below:

©⃥

However, the solidus extends beyond the edge of the Copyright symbol in an asymmetric manner.

Wikipedia indicates there is a [combining diacritical mark for a symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks_for_Symbols) that is a circle with a slash:

◌⃠

How can I combine the Circle with Slash to the letter C? Is there a better way to add a slash mark to the Copyright symbol so that it doesn't extend unevenly beyond its boundaries?

[image: public domain mark]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Public Domain Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Domain_Mark) symbol is already encoded in Unicode as `U+1F16E  CIRCLED C WITH OVERLAID BACKSLASH` which was added in Unicode 13.0.

All the Unicode symbols related to the [Creative Commons license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Unicode_symbols) are:

- ⊜ U+229C  CIRCLED EQUALS
- U+1F10D CIRCLED ZERO WITH SLASH
- U+1F10E CIRCLED ANTICLOCKWISE ARROW
- U+1F10F CIRCLED DOLLAR SIGN WITH OVERLAID BACKSLASH
- U+1F16D CIRCLED CC
- U+1F16E CIRCLED C WITH OVERLAID BACKSLASH
- U+1F16F CIRCLED HUMAN FIGURE